# VpnService always-on "not supported by this app"

Tags: android, android-vpn-service

I'm trying to write a VPN application for android, and no matter what I do it seems that the "Always On" setting for my application is grayed out.

I cannot find any documentation anywhere in the android docs that states WHY a VpnService might not be allowed to use the "Always On" feature.

Just to make sure I'm clear, my VpnService works just fine if i manually enable it. I'm able to connect, use it, etc without any issues. I'm just confused as to why in the Android settings it's showing as "not supported for this device" under the "Always-On" toggle for my Vpn Service.

> Note: I am using a custom protocol, and on some forum somewhere I did see once that "Google doesn't allow Always-On for VPNs that don't use protocols that have been whitelisted by google", however no where have I found documentation to support this claim, so I'm doubtful that it is the cause.

**What I have found from reading the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html):**

1. If you explicitly supply the [SERVICE_META_DATA_SUPPORTS_ALWAYS_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html#SERVICE_META_DATA_SUPPORTS_ALWAYS_ON) flag to the `<service>` definition in your Android Manafest with a value of `false` it will tell the system that your application does not support the Always On feature. However, if you leave it out, it defaults to `true`. So there should be no need to supply this.
2. According to the Android Souce in [AppManagementFragment.java#updateRestrictedViews](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/vpn2/AppManagementFragment.java#242), it uses a function `mConnectivityManager.isAlwaysOnVpnPackageSupportedForUser(mUserId, mPackageName)`, however I'm having difficulty following the logic of this function. When looking at [ConnectivityManager.java#isAlwaysOnVpnPackageSupportedForUser](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java#1026), it seems to end up in [ConnectivityService.java#isAlwaysOnVpnPackageSupported](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#L4611) and **ultimately** points to [Vpn.java#isAlwaysOnPackageSupported](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/Vpn.java#L408) which can result in your VPN being considered to NOT support always on if *one* of the following is met:

   1. The package name passed to the function is null.
   2. The system is unable to locate the package using `PackageManager. getApplicationInfoAsUser()`.
   3. The target for the application is less than `VERSION_CODES.N`
   4. The package does not contain any Vpn Services in its `AndroidManifest.xml`.
   5. The package defines ANY VpnServices with the `SERVICE_META_DATA_SUPPORTS_ALWAYS_ON` meta data set to `false`.

> Note: My application targets API 29.

And that's about it.

Since my application meets all of the requirements stated in `Vpn.java#isAlwaysOnPackageSupported`, i'm left very confused as to why it will not work.

> I've created an android studio project that demonstrates this happening on my Samsung Galaxy S10. You can [find it here on github](https://github.com/nathan-fiscaletti/android-vpn-always-on-not-supported).

**My code for reference:**

My service is configured as is documented in the Android Documentation.

```xml
<service
    android:name=".provider.VpnProvider"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE"
    android:description="@string/service_description"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.VpnSerivce" />
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

In my Dashboard activity, I use this to handle the `Connect` button being tapped.

```java
public static final int REQ_START_VPN = 40;

public boolean connect() {
    Intent intent;

    try {
        intent = VpnProvider.prepare(this.getApplicationContext());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        return false;
    }

    if (intent != null) {
        try {
            this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_START_VPN);
            return true;
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            new BasicDialog(
                this, R.string.not_supported,
                R.string.not_supported_message
            ).show();
        }
    } else {
        this.onActivityResult(REQ_START_VPN, AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK, null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I then handle the result using the following:

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_START_VPN) {
            try {
                this.startService(new Intent(this, VpnProvider.class));
            } catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {}
        }
    }
}
```

My `VpnProvider` class extends `VpnService` and has the following for Building the interface:

```java
VpnService.Builder builder = this.new Builder();
builder.setMtu(mtu);
builder.addAddress("1.2.3.4", 32);
builder.addDnsServer("8.8.8.8");
builder.addDnsServer("8.8.4.4");
builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
vpnInterface = builder.establish();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem.

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` when I declared the intent-filters for my service I had a typo.

```
<action android:name="android.net.VpnSerivce" />
```

instead of

```
<action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
```

This made my application not inform the operating system that my application had a VpnService as documented in the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn#add_a_service).

This typo took three days of my life that I will never get back.